# How to render only one object, that is still affected by the volumetric and lights in Eevee?

Tags: rendering, render-layers

I made a background and placed an image plane, whith the keyed out footage of a musician into the scene. I now want to only render out the musician (image plane) in Eevee. I made it to render (while disable the render buttons from the other objects), but the volumetrics were gone. How to render the image plane, while keeping the volumetrics and lights, without seeing them?  I can't understand, why this is so tricky, haven't found a solution in the last two days :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If I were to set up the render layers, I'd do volumetrics separately and stencil out the musician and background.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to composite in after effetcs, therefore I want the musician layer by itself.

Comment: If you want to color correct or do any kind of comp, mixing volumetrics and actor would be bad, because the base colors would already be inaccessible. Separate both into different layers as I suggested.

Comment: Do I need to screen blend the volumetric layer over the actor in after effects in order to have the same look as in blender?